# Use ggplot to plot several histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im looking for a way to plot to subsets of a dataset over each other. I have the following df, that kind a looks like this (geboortejaar = "birthyear" and geboorteland = "country of birth"):

```
     Geboortejaar     Geboorteland       month
1    23-9-1980      Germany        9
2   18-12-1968      Germany        12
3   29-12-1967      Netherlands    12
```

library(ggplot2)

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = month)) +
 + geom_histogram(data=subset(df, Geboorteland == "Netherlands"),    fill="red", alpha = 0.2) +
 + geom_histogram(data=subset(df, Geboorteland == "Germany"), fill="blue", alpha = 0.2)
```

But this gives me a histogram that is stacked. Im looking for two histograms plots over each other.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the *Grammar of Graphics*, i.e., map the colors to data and specify a scale. You then need to specify use of `position_indentity` instead of the default `position_stack`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = month)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = Geboorteland), position = "identity", alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Germany" = "blue", "Netherlands" = "red"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer this one for comparing two distributions:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = ..density.., fill = Geboorteland)) +
  geom_histogram(position = 'dodge')
```

You should adjust the 'binwidth' in geom_histogram() to suit your needs.

Comment: I don't think dodging is appropriate for a histogram. I would use facetting instead.

Comment: I find it very useful in comparing two distributions vs. faceting, which truly does not easily allow me to see differences.